# Law against putting people down?

Tags: halacha, speech-talking, middos-character-traits

I recall hearing a few years ago about a law in scripture regarding one's speech that had a particular Jewish interpretation that resonated with me. The problem is, I don't remember what it was called, or all of the specifics of the interpretation.

As I recall, much the spirit of the interpretation was about putting people down or making them feel stupid. One example might be if an expert in a field (say, a lawyer) asked a known non-expert (a non-lawyer) if he could explain the intricacies of some concept in that field of expertise with the intent of exposing him as someone who does not know what he is talking about.

If I recall, asking a question to which you know the answer already was another aspect of that same interpretation.

The law might have been translated as something like "bad mouth", though I think that slander might not have been included because that implies that the bad-mouthing is false.

So here's the three-parter:

- What is the law?
- Did I understand it aright?
- Is there a "standard" set of aspects to this law/interpretation? If so, what are they?

Comment: Could this refer to the prohibition against embarrassing another person (discussed here: http://www.torah.org/learning/jewish-values/hurtfulwords3.html )?

Comment: From http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37240/embarassing-an-anonymous-person-online : "There is a prohibition to embarass other people (Sanhedrin 99a)."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the addition to your question:

> The law might have been translated as something like "bad mouth", though I think that slander might not have been included because that implies that the bad-mouthing is false.

— I have to say you must be referring to [*lashon hara*, "evil speech"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lashon_hara), which is (very generally) telling true tales that hurt someone. Yes, there are standards of this. [Rabbi *Yisrael Meir* Kagan/Kahan (died 1933)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yisrael_Meir_Kagan) wrote a law book about it, called *Chafetz Chayim*, and a morality book about it, called *Sh'miras Halashon*. [Both are now available in their entirety (I think) in English.](http://www.feldheim.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=mazal+elul)

Comment: That's the one!

Comment: For the record, the Biblical prohibition against [*ona'at devarim*](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9712/law-against-putting-people-down/9713#9713) is one of the many that the *Chafetz Chayim* lists as transgressed when one speaks *lashon hara*.

Comment: I see! Very interesting, and it definitely gives a broader perspective on ways that we might make people feel inferior, and what's going on when we do that. I'm going to accept this answer, since it was the term I was looking for, but upvotes all around :)

Comment: It's *Lashon HaRa* even if it's true; if it's false it's even worse, it's called *motzee shem ra*. If the hurtful words are heard by their subject it's also *ona'at devarim*; if I just spread it around his back it's not *ona't devarim*, but I have violated the curse of *striking one's fellow secretly* (he walks in to work one day and finds he's fired; he never found out it was because someone sent a false report to HR.)

Answer (score 9):

It's known as *ona'at devarim*. Taking advantage by words, or [as Rabbi Torczyner calls it, verbal abuse.](http://www.webshas.org/dibbur/onaah.htm)

The example of asking someone unknowledgeable to put them down is discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/mi-shaino-yodeya/1558#1558), by *Shulhan Arukh* in the laws of Ona'at Devarim.

Leviticus 24:14-17:

> כה,יד וכי-תמכרו ממכר לעמיתך, או קנה מיד עמיתך--אל-תונו, איש את-אחיו.  כה,טו במספר שנים אחר היובל, תקנה ...  כה,יז ולא תונו איש את-עמיתו, ויראת מאלהיך
>
> When you sell to your fellow, or buy from him, one person should not take advantage of one another: you shall buy according to the number of years after Jubilee ... [additionally], **and one person shall not take advantage of one another, and you shall fear your G-d.**

The Talmud notes that the first prohibition was on cheating someone when selling; the second is something that requires fear of G-d as no one may ever know whether I said something innocently, or with intention to put someone down: taking advantage of them with words.

Rabbi Samson Raphael Hirsch explains that the root here *ona'a* is related to *koneh*, to acquire ownership of something. Often putting someone down is a way of trying to *own* them.

See Torczyner's link above for more.

Comment: This is a very helpful and detailed answer, but, (I hate to say it), I don't think this was the one that I had in mind. :-\

Comment: @Ray, If there's any additional detail that you could add to your question to get us closer to what you're looking for, it could be helpful.

Comment: I've added some more detail.. if my memory serves correctly. I hope I'm not conflating a couple of different concepts.